# Solr modify search terms before run query

Tags: solr, lucene, lemmatization

As same as this plugin does it at index time (Implementing a conditional copyField)
https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateRequestProcessor
I would like to do the same thing at query time.

I used this plugin to lemmatize texts once and then copy the lemmatized text to different fields.

I would like to do the same thing at query time but I can't find how to (or not as easily I found this).

So what I want is if the user search for X, do this on a plugin:
y = process_text(y)
and supossing we have title and body make this search:
title:y body:y
Or maybe we need the original text for another field
title:y body:y otherfield:x
Is there any example that modifies the query terms?
Thank you all

---

**I'm going to explain it better.**

I have those fields:
text_en, text_en2de, text_de, text_de2en

I made a lemmatizer for english, german texts. The lemmatizer needs time to lemmatize texts.

On query time, I use the plugin that I said and I lemmatize the text only once. Then the lemmatized text is copied to those fields.

**But** If I have to make a search on text_en, text_de2en... I have to lemmatize **once per field** and It tooks time.

That's why I want to make a plugin on query time to get the q field, lemmatize the text and then redirect this lemmatized text to the fields I want.

For example if I make a custom SearchHandler (I think I have to do this, but I didn't found any examples) I would configure it

```
<requestHandler name="/select_en" class="CustomSearchHandler">
<lst name="defaults">
<int name="langs">de</int>
```

Then If I make a search like **q="running"**
The plugin would get this texts and make a search on

```
text_en=run&text_de2en=run
```

Comment: you can use the different fieldsType for different fields and achieve this...

Comment: And then you need to use the Dismax or eDismax QueryHandler to spread the search terms across several fields with different fieldTypes